# Get users based on month ACF datepicker field

Tags: customization, custom-field, filters, advanced-custom-fields, date

I have an ACF field 'date_of_birth' which stores the user's birthday, examples: 20201226, 20151225, 19980701

**Goal**: get all users which have their birthday this month, or next month.

I currently have this:

```
    $users_start_date_boundary = gmdate( 'Ymd', strtotime( '-1 month' ) );
    $users_end_date_boundary   = gmdate( 'Ymd', strtotime( '+2 month' ) );

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(
        [
            'fields'     => 'all_with_meta',
            'orderby'    => 'date_of_birth',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key'     => 'date_of_birth',
                    'value'   => [ $users_start_date_boundary, $users_end_date_boundary ],
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );

    return $wp_user_query->get_results();
```

The problem with this however, that it only gets users with a birthyear of 2020.

How do I get all users, based on the given month boundaries, while ignoring the year/day the person is born in?

Comment: WP / the db could have a problem with the format the dates is in. Can you instead save it as a timestamp? Or well formatted (i.e. `2020-12-26`)?

Comment: @kero ACF doesn't allow database configurations, I'll have to deal with the current format. I can't save it as a timestamp, but I can use a date time picker instead of a datepicker if that would help

Comment: You definitely need a more complex code to do what you want, and I have an idea what is needed to be done. Unfortunately (or fortunately :) ) I don't use ACF with any of my sites so to test it I need to know how exactly this meta field appeared in the database. Can you attach an example to you question?

Comment: @IvanShatsky What do you mean / what more info do you need? [The doc](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) describes the format as `YYYYMMDD` and says it cannot be changed.

Comment: @kero I mean that I need to know how that meta field is appeared in the `wp_usermeta` database. For example, `user_id` is the user ID (that's obvious), `meta_key` is `"date_of_birth"` string, `meta_value` is a 8 digit length string. The only way I see to solve this is to alter the query low level via the `get_meta_sql` hook (and it won't be an easy task).

Comment: @kero Well, there can be one more way, using the `get_user_metadata` hook. Anyway I need to know how the database metadata record looks like.

Comment: I think you're going to have to write your own SQL query to do this, rather than using WP_User_Query. You probably want the MONTH() function to extract the month field from the date. However I don't think the meta value will be stored as a MySQL date, so maybe you might have to use a substring match? Either way I'd start by getting the query working in SQL.

Comment: @Rup I agreed, using substring match/comparsion is the only way to solve this. Maybe you are right, writing own SQL query would be easier than altering WP-generated one via `get_meta_sql` hook.

Comment: @Rup The problem with a custom query will be retrieving the users, since you cannot query then for multiple IDs (as far as I understood).

Comment: @IvanShatsky Alternatively, you can just store the month in an additional meta field using the `acf/update_value` hook and then use the `>=` and `<=` meta query on that field. Btw the [meta values should look like this](https://pastebin.com/K0Rushkv)

Comment: @kero The month and the day of month you want to say, i.e. the substring of last four digits of the meta value. I'm not familiar with the ACF but if it has such a hook this could be definitely a solution too, and the whole code would be much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code based on custom SQL query as suggested by @Rup that should work for you:

```php
// get '-1 month' and '+2 month' dates as an array('YYYY', 'MMDD')
$before = str_split( gmdate( 'Ymd', strtotime( '-1 month' ) ), 4 );
$after = str_split( gmdate( 'Ymd', strtotime( '+2 month' ) ), 4 );
// if the before/after years are the same, should search for date >= before AND <= after
// if the before/after years are different, should search for date >= before OR <= after
$cmp = ( $before[0] == $after[0] ) ? 'AND' : 'OR';
// SQL query
$users = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = %s AND (SUBSTRING(meta_value, 5, 4) >= '%s' %s SUBSTRING(meta_value, 5, 4) <= '%s')",
    'date_of_birth', $before[1], $cmp, $after[1]
));
```

**Update**

Maybe I misunderstand your question looking at your code. The above code would give the list of users whose birthday passed no more than month ago or will happen no more than two months after the current date. To get the list of all users which have their birthday this month or next month, use the following code:

```
$current = gmdate( 'm' );
$next = sprintf( "%02d", $current % 12 + 1 );
$users = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = %s AND (SUBSTRING(meta_value, 5, 2) = '%s' OR SUBSTRING(meta_value, 5, 2) = '%s')",
    'date_of_birth', $current, $next
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe since ACF stores the values as `Ymd` you have to write some kind of workaround. One possible solution could be that you hook into saving the field and additionally store the month in another meta field. This would allow to query for `=>` and `<=` with the meta query.

Another solution is to not store the date in an arbitrary format but one that the database understands and then using the database's existing functions.

```
\add_filter('acf/update_value/type=date_picker', function($value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        return $value;
    }

    $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value);
    return $dt->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
});

\add_filter('acf/load_value/type=date_picker', function($value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        return $value;
    }

    $dt = new \DateTime($value);
    return $dt->format('Ymd');
});
```

These two filters will change any date picker to store the date in a well formed date string (like `2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00`) which can easily be understood by the database. You can also just target this specific field, read more about it ([doc for `acf/update_value`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-update_value/) and [doc for `acf/load_value`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_value/)). (**Attention!** If you already have dates saved in the db, you should manually transform them to new format before applying this code change!)

To retrieve the user IDs you can use [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) with a custom query like so

```
$month = date('m');
$userIds = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = %s AND (MONTH(meta_value) = %d OR MONTH(meta_value) = %d)",
    'date_of_birth',
    $month,
    ($month % 12) + 1
));
```

(`($month % 12) + 1` will get the next month, see [this explanation](https://maurobringolf.ch/2017/12/bug-report-compute-the-5-next-months-with-modulo-arithmetic/))

It seems that `WP_User_Query` is not able to retrieve a list of users by their ID, so you would need to call [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) for each user ID, which is probably not optimal - but that depends on your use case.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it ignores the year the person was born in. If someone was born in 1998, on December 12th it woudn't match in your example.

Comment: @fanatic21221 Ah .. you're right - I was too quick, sorry. Let me re-think this issue. Would it be a solution to change how ACF stores/retrieves date or do you have this already running and would need to update existing values?

Comment: @fanatic21221 Please see the updated solution.